# Find the number of ways to paint the faces of a regular tetrahedron using 4 different colours.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways to paint the faces of a regular tetrahedron using 4 different colours. All colours must be used. Two colourings are identical if the tetrahedrons can be rotated to look identical.

Answer (score 3):

While the general approach to this sort of problem is to use Burnside's Lemma, in this case the count is small enough that you can do it by hand.

First put the Red face at the bottom, and then rotate it so that the Blue face is in front of you. There are two more faces, rear left and rear right, which must get Green and Yellow. Thus there are two ways to do it, one with Green rear left and the other with Green rear right.

Burnside's Lemma gives $( (1)(24)+0+0+...+0) / 12 = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is more of an abstract algebra question than a probability question. You may wish to look up Burnside's Counting Theorem. Sorry, I am in a rush so I can't type much more.

Watch this youtube video to get an idea of what to do.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITu8iXuKRd4

If you are not allowed to use, or do not know abstract algebra yet do this.
Think about the total number of colorings not worrying about rotational symmetry (This is 4^4). Then consider how many of those colorings are removed when you look at rotations case by case. This will involve some boots to the ground computation.

Comment: Since all four colors must be used, there are only $4! =24$ colorings (disregarding symmetries), not $4^4$.

Comment: You are correct! My mistake.